# How to find LCD of two polynomials in $Z_3=\{0,1,2\}?$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have to find LCD of $x^3+x^2+2x+2$ and $x^2+x+1.$ Then I get quotient $x$ and remainder $x+2.$ The division of $x^2+x+1$ and $x+2$ gives quotient $x-1$ and remainder $0.$ Is this good because we have as a quotient $x-1,$ and we only calculate with positive numbers? Should I write $x+2$ instead of $x-1?$

Comment: It doesn't matter (unless you're a student whose teacher has stated a preference, in which case, do what she tells you).

Comment: What is LCD? GCD or LCM?

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see that both polynomials have as many roots over $\Bbb F_3$ as their degree is, so that
$$
x^3+x^2+2x+2=(x + 2)(x + 1)^2,\quad x^2+x+1=(x+2)^2.
$$
From this one can directly derive the greatest common divisors and least common multiples.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^3+x^2+2x+2=(x^2+2)(x+1)=(x^2-1)(x+1)=(x-1)(x+1)^2=(x+2)(x+1)^2$

and $x^2+x+1=x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2=(x+2)^2$

Thus GCD$=x+2$ and LCM$=(x+2)^2(x+1)^2$